# Uri to Resource ID

Tags: android, resources, uri, soundpool

I need to convert my Uri into a Res ID. Is this possible? I need it because I have .mp3s on my SD card that I want to put into SoundPool which only takes Res ID's. Note: (**Cant use MediaPlayer,** need soundpool functions)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urrrm, can't you use [SoundPool.load(String path, int priority)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and create your path strings from the Uris?

Comment: What hashmap? You didn't mention a hashmap in your original question. You simply stated that SoundPool "only takes Res ID's" which is not true. Reword your question and explain what you want to do and what the problem is.